# Buttons are doing actions assigned to other buttons via actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I just have a small problem with my code; I'm currently using a cardlayout wherein I currently have 3 buttons. 1(on the initial panel) adds JLabels to the initial panel,another(also on the initial panel) switches to the second panel which just contains the 3rd button that returns to the initial panel. My problem is that clicking the buttons for swapping between panels also triggers the first button which creates JLabels.

Here is part of my code:

```
actionListener al = new actionListener();   
actionListener al2 = new actionListener();
actionListener al3 = new actionListener();

adddeck.addActionListener(al);//creates JLabels on panel1
addcardbutton.addActionListener(al2);//goes to panel2
goback.addActionListener(al3)//returns to panel1
```

Then the actionlistener part:

```
public class actionListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JButton src = (JButton) event.getSource();

        if(event.getSource()==adddeck)
        decklist.add(new Deck(newdeck.getText()));              
        //panel for label/buttons
        JPanel deckpanel;
        deckpanel= new JPanel();
        deckpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        //label with new deck name
        JLabel decklabel;
        decklabel = new JLabel(newdeck.getText());                       
        deckpanel.add(decklabel);
        deckpanel.revalidate();
        //label with # of cards
        JLabel cardamt;             
        cardamt = new JLabel(i +"cards");
        deckpanel.add(cardamt);
        deckpanel.revalidate();         
        //add panel
        initial.add(deckpanel);
        initial.revalidate();

        if(event.getSource()==addcardbutton)
        cardLayout.show(contentPanel,"adding");

        if(event.getSource()==goback)
        cardLayout.show(contentPanel,"initial");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not used curly braces (`{`) for the `if` statements. When an `if` statement does not have curly braces, only the line just after `if` is included in the `if` block.

For example your code

```
if(event.getSource()==adddeck)
decklist.add(new Deck(newdeck.getText()));              
//panel for label/buttons
JPanel deckpanel;
deckpanel= new JPanel();
deckpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
//label with new deck name
JLabel decklabel;
decklabel = new JLabel(newdeck.getText());                       
deckpanel.add(decklabel);
deckpanel.revalidate();
```

is equivalent to:

```
if(event.getSource()==adddeck) {
  decklist.add(new Deck(newdeck.getText()));
}              
//panel for label/buttons
JPanel deckpanel;
deckpanel= new JPanel();
deckpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
//label with new deck name
JLabel decklabel;
decklabel = new JLabel(newdeck.getText());                       
deckpanel.add(decklabel);
deckpanel.revalidate();
```

So, the code starts from line `//panel for label/buttons` is always executed regardless of the button you click.